# MongoDB - How to move an array from one array field to another

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-update

I have two fields in a MongoDB document `publish` and `draft` with schema as:

```js
{
    publish: [[
                { type: String, required: true },
                { type: String, required: true }
            ]],
    draft: [[
                { type: String, required: true },
                { type: String, required: true }
            ]]
}
```

and value looks like this in DB:

```
{
    "draft": [
        [
          "Panic 2",
          "63d2648d373f7fea3fa9d387_1681628752497"
        ],
        //...
      ],
      "publish": [
        [
          "Ruins Exploration Gone Wrong!",
          "63d2648d373f7fea3fa9d387_1681628787816"
        ],
        [
          "Fresh Start",
          "63d2648d373f7fea3fa9d387_1681628805269"
        ],
        //...
      ]
}
```

Now I'm working on a query that can move the array

```
["Panic 2","63d2648d373f7fea3fa9d387_1681628752497"]
```

from `draft` to `publish` but I only have `63d2648d373f7fea3fa9d387_1681628752497` to achieve so.

How should I frame my query?

EDIT: I have tried some way and was able to pull the array from `draft` field but haven't been able to push that array to `publish` with only the presence of id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the second element within the inner array is unique, you can perform the update with aggregation pipeline:

1. `$set`

   `selected` - Filter the matching element for the id value from the `draft` array.

   `draft` - Filter the element to remove it (`selected`) from the `draft` array.
2. `$set`

   `published` - Combine the `selected` array with `published` array.

   `selected` - Remove the `selected` field.

```
db.collection.update({
  "draft": {
    $elemMatch: {
      $elemMatch: {
        $eq: "63d2648d373f7fea3fa9d387_1681628752497"
      }
    }
  }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      selected: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$draft",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  "$$this",
                  1
                ]
              },
              "63d2648d373f7fea3fa9d387_1681628752497"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      draft: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$draft",
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  "$$this",
                  1
                ]
              },
              "63d2648d373f7fea3fa9d387_1681628752497"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      publish: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$publish",
          "$selected"
        ]
      },
      selected: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4MOcLZ299a4)

Comment: why double $elemMatch?

Comment: Because you want to find the value within the `draft` array which is nested array. Without double `$elemMatch`, it won't able to filter any document.